# How to upgrade Redis and ElasticSearch in Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, redis, magento-cloud

I'm running a Magento 2.3 Cloud with many issues related to Redis requests.

We run the Redis 3, and the recommended version to have a better performance in the dev docs is the version 5 to M2.3, the same to Elasticsearch 6.8 instead of 6.5.

I wonder if I can upgrade the Redis version just changing the version in the **services.yaml** file?

```
mysql:
    type: mysql:10.0
    disk: 8192

redis:
    type: redis:3.0

elasticsearch:
    type: elasticsearch:6.5
    disk: 1024
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if you're on Magento Starter or Magento Pro.

Updating the `services.yaml` file will update your development environments, and production if you're using **Magento Starter**.  That will let you verify that your Magento code and any custom extensions play nicely with the new versions.

If you're on **Magento Pro**, then to update your staging and production environments, open a support ticket and the support team can take care of it.  Redis should be easy, but Elasticsearch will take some coordination as it will need to have the index rebuild after the upgrade.  The support team can help schedule that with you.

Cheers.